# Transformation of support domain

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to compute the following integral
\begin{equation}
 \int_{-0.5}^{0.5} \int_{-2}^{-0.5} \left(\left(x-\alpha \right)^2+\left(y-\beta \right)^2 \right)-\left(x^2+y^2 \right) dydx.
\end{equation}
I want to change the support region from a rectangle into a circle. To do this I choose, $x=r \cos(\theta)$, and $y = r \sin (\theta)$. I am struggling to compute value of $r$ and $\theta$.

Comment: You can split the formula and use change of variables separately

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment UESTCfresh. Could you kindly explain it a little more?

Answer (score 0):

For \begin{equation}
 \int_{-0.5}^{0.5} \int_{-2}^{-0.5} \left(\left(x-\alpha \right)^2+\left(y-\beta \right)^2 \right)-\left(x^2+y^2 \right) dydx.
\end{equation}, we split it into two parts:
\begin{equation}
 \int_{-0.5}^{0.5} \int_{-2}^{-0.5} \left(\left(x-\alpha \right)^2+\left(y-\beta \right)^2 \right)dydx.
\end{equation} and \begin{equation}
 \int_{-0.5}^{0.5} \int_{-2}^{-0.5} -\left(x^2+y^2 \right) dydx.
\end{equation}

For the first, we can substitue $x- \alpha$ with $u$ and substitue $y- \beta$ with $v$. Then it is transformed to:
\begin{equation}
 \int_{-0.5-\beta}^{0.5-\beta} \int_{-2-\alpha}^{-0.5-\alpha} \left(u^2+v^2 \right) dvdu
\end{equation}. Then it is easy to use polar coordinate now.